# Verificação entre hora em um período

Tags: php

Bom estou tentando criar uma função que me retorna true/false com base em um determinado período de hora. Ela compra a hora atual do servidor e verifica se esta dentro do período informado.

Exemplo:

```
function Verifica_Expediente ($inicio, $fim) {

    // Coleta dados
    $hora1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d' . $inicio));
    $hora2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d' . $fim));
    $agora = time();

    // Verifica horas
    if ($hora1 <= $agora && $agora <= $hora2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Verifica_Expediente ("10:00:00", "14:30:00");
```

Quando eu informo o início de 10:00h até 14:40h e o servidor estiver dentro desse período, a funcção me retorna `true`.

O problema e quando eu uso um período que vira o dia, ou seja que a hora fim é menor pois ela é referente ao outro dia. Exemplo: 18:00h até 8:00h.

Alguém sabe como posso verificar isso? Preciso identificar que o dia mudou.

Comment: Você poderia realizar verificação do dia e da hora? ou precisa ser necessariamente APENAS a hora?

Comment: Sim, tem que ser apenas da hora. Quero programar o sistema para identificar o horário de funcionamento de uma empresa e me notificar de qualquer acesso feito ao sistema sem estar no horário de funcionamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar classes espicíficas pra trabalhar com data e hora, como o [date time](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), pois ela tem suporte pra essa questão de diferença de dias.
Você ainda pode também, trabalhar com uma classe mais completa que extende a date time, que é o [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), todas elas você tem suporte pra isso que você precisa, pois internamente na classe, eles tem o controle de dia, mês e ano.
No seu caso, pelo que entendi, você tem apenas o horário como uma string, e não tem esse controle.

[Exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8) do que você precisa fazer com a classe date time:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$d1 = new DateTime('2008-08-03 14:52:10');
$d2 = new DateTime('2008-01-03 11:11:10');
var_dump($d1 == $d2); #bool(false)
var_dump($d1 > $d2); #bool(true)
var_dump($d1 < $d2); #bool(false)
?>
```

E com o [Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps) você tem alguns métodos que são os

```
*eq() equals

*ne() not equals

*gt() greater than

*gte() greater than or equals

*lt() less than

*lte() less than or equals
```

[Exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684111/how-to-compare-two-carbon-timestamps) de uso do carbon com uma coluna timestamps no banco de dados

```
if($model->edited_at->gt($model->created_at)){
    // edited at is newer than created at
}
```